# How to display the google map loction enter by the user in drupal7

Tags: drupal-7, geolocation, geomap

I am new for drupal and using drupal7 I want to know how to display the google map,the location enter by the user.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You could use these modules [Geolocation Views](https://drupal.org/project/geolocation_views) + [Location Map](https://drupal.org/project/locationmap)

[Geolocation Views](https://drupal.org/project/geolocation_views) mark to map

[Location Map](https://drupal.org/project/locationmap) show all marks and filter